# Getting info from 2 cell in a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've a match calender for a sports club with a table Matches
'id','home','away','score'

In the home and away column are the team ID's

The team names are in the Teams table
'id', 'name', 'logo'

I'm generating the table with 
select * from Matches order by date asc

Then I get the ID's in the output.
I could use a join like
select * from Matches, Teams where Matches.home=Teams.id but that only works to resolve one id into a name.
How can I fix this to get both names (home & away?
FYI: I use this in combination with PHP

Comment: add sample data ,expected output and tried php script

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) syntax. Like this:

```
SELECT
    Matches.id,
    Matches.score,
    TeamHome.name AS HomeTeam,
    TeamAway.name AS AwayTeam
FROM
    Matches
    JOIN Teams AS TeamHome
        ON Matches.home=TeamHome.id
    JOIN Teams AS TeamAway
        ON Matches.away=TeamAway.id
```

Or if `home` and `away` is nullable it might make sense to use `LEFT JOIN`'s. Like this:

```
SELECT
    Matches.id,
    Matches.score,
    TeamHome.name AS HomeTeam,
    TeamAway.name AS AwayTeam
FROM
    Matches
    LEFT JOIN Teams AS TeamHome
        ON Matches.home=TeamHome.id
    LEFT JOIN Teams AS TeamAway
        ON Matches.away=TeamAway.id
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all with `JOIN` you should use `ON` clause, not `WHERE`. And secondly - you can join same table more than once:

```
SELECT * FROM Matches
    JOIN Teams as Home ON Matches.home = Home.id
    JOIN Teams as Away ON Matches.away = Away.id
```